# How to get a blurred background using a Canon 18-55 STM lens?

Tags: aperture, focal-length, depth-of-field, camera-settings, canon-70d

I'm totally new to photography and need your help.

I've read much about ISO, Aperture and Shutter speed. I know to get a blurred backround: use a wide aperture. Also I know the distance between camera and object is important.

But every single time I've tried to get a blurred background, I've achieved nothing! I was thinking maybe it's not possible to have this effect with a 18-55mm STM lens at all. This is on a Canon 70D

Is that right? If not, what is your recommended setting to get a blurred background?

Best shot I could get is this. f/5.6, 1/250, ISO auto:

[image]

Comment: It could be helpful if you post an example of one of your attempts. It certainly is possible to take photos with a blurred background with this lens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get as much as distance between the object in focus and the background along with max zoom and aperture the widest.

Apart from these basics, many times I've experienced using manual focus helps a lot.What I mean is to more perfectly focus on the object of focus. Many times my auto focus, focuses on something else too hence, I lose sharpness on the in focus object.

Comment: This is correct... until the last sentence which is just wrong. Using manual focus has not effect whatsoever on your depth of field.

Comment: What I meant was to more perfectly focus on the object of focus. Many times my auto focus, focuses on something else too hence, I lose sharpness on the in focus object.

Comment: That's still a very different problem - and to be honest, sounds more like you need to learn how to use your autofocus system better. If you've got good separation between your subject and the background, an SLR shouldn't have any real trouble focusing on the subject.

Comment: @samjay, just edit the last part to clarify then.

Comment: Today I could take a new shot as you can see in attached pic. It's not great but it's my first ahooying and so excited :d However, sometimes I wasn't able to blure background and the object itself was blured! Just as a question, what lense do you expert usually use for getting the best blured background in nature?

Comment: @Mechatronics "sometimes I wasn't able to blur background and the object itself was blurred!"... that is the definition of an out-of-focus photograph. Before concerning yourself with the background, make sure you are focusing on your subject!